# Does Prince support edged indexes/bleed tabs?

Tags: princexml

Is there any way to configure `PrinceXML` to print edge indexes/bleed tabs?

for example a phone book, with edges A, B, C....

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think so, sorry! (I'm a developer for DocRaptor, the Prince-based API service).

Comment: thanks! i guess this is an answer,so  if you can post it as such, ill be glad to accept it. (the answer, not the fact there's no option :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an option in Prince, sorry. It may be possible with some printer-specific PDF options, but there is no default way to define bleed tabs in Prince.